# How to use a <nav> tag in more than one pages

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using a nav tag in index page and also want to use that in second page but I want to remain just one same css file. Now the problem is that if I will change .nav styling in css file for second page then it will be change in index page. 
Should I make separate css files for every page or is there any other solution as well?

I tried to give id to nav in second html page to make it different in the css file but it is not making changing in second page nav.

one

        two

        three

It should be change in the second page.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to your  element and reference that particular class. For example:

```
<nav class="nav-style-1">...</nav>
<nav class="nav-style-2">...</nav>


.nav-style-1 { your styles ... }
.nav-style-2 { your styles ... }
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is, if you want to continue with same CSS file, you can add id property to each navbar and use id to give them specific CSS attributes.

Answer (score 0):

People doing wordpress themes have the same requirement as you. Their solution is to add an id tag to the body element.

Their CSS rules look something like ...

```
#page1 .nav {
 ...  your nav css rules for page 1 ...
}
#page2 .page2 {
... add a style to all items on page two with the class of page2.
}
#page3 .page3 {
... custom style that appears only on page3 ...
}
```

The HTML

```
<body id="page1">

<!-- menu -->
<ul class="menu">
<li class="homepage">
<li class="page1">
<li class="page2">
<li class="page3">
</ul>
```

Rule [#page1 .page1] only has an effect when .page1 is a and element in #page1 which only happens on page1. So I can highlight the menu item that corresponds to the page which is loaded.